# Heroku page won't load with proper css

Tags: html, .htaccess, heroku

H, I'm using heroku to host a php/mysql webapp. The problem is that the page will load when you go to the app page, but without any of the css. If I append `/public_html/index.php` to the url, then I can see the css again.

Before I modified my .htaccess file, going to the home page would give me a 404 or 403 error, so I added this line to it:

`DirectoryIndex public_html/index.php`

In my index.php file, the code linking to the css is `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">`

My directory tree is pretty simple, and the structure is like this (everything is within a `Rhymes` folder):

```
>public_html
  >css
    styles.css
  >img
  >js
    jquery.js
    results.js
  index.php
  test.php (random test page)
>resources
  >db_results.php
.htaccess
composer.json
```

I'm not familiar with .htaccess that much, but I feel the problem is either there or the css link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use either absolute paths, prepend your css path with `/` like below or use the base tag.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css"
```

or you can put this in the `head` section of your site.

```
<base href="http://example.com/">
```

This will make sure all links are rendered correctly.

Also if your htaccess is in public_html, your directory index should just be.

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that, but then the css doesn't load locally. Haven't tried uploading it yet though.

Comment: It should still load locally using the `/` just tells it to start at the root.

Comment: Thanks, but what's the php code to automatically detect and change the base tag if I'm locally testing, vs online?

Comment: I changed the .htaccess file, added this to the head (since all my files are within the rhymes folder), and have the css link like this: `<base href="http://localhost/rhymes/">` and `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">` but the css isn't loading on my local machine..?

Comment: Use Chrome or FF dev tools (F12) to see what path it's trying to load. you'll see a 404 error in the console and that will tell you what path it's trying to load.

Comment: So I changed the .htaccess back to what I had it since that file was in the root directory and then I changed the href link to `<link rel="stylesheet" href="public_html/css/styles.css">` and that got it to work. I'm not sure why that worked however. Should I give you the correct answer, or something? I'm not really sure what happens in this case...

Comment: Ok cool. Your setup is a little off, but as long as you got it to work that's good. It's up to you if you want to give me the answer with how much I helped you. I was the only one that answered anyway. :) However what I said does work in 95% of CSS loading issues when rewrite/htaccess comes in to play. That's a common problem.

Comment: Oh, how is it off? Do you know any resources I could use to correctly structure my web apps/pages for future reference?

Comment: i don't have any resources off hand, but `public_html` is supposed to be your document root or `/` of your site. So it should not need to be included in any URL's at all. So your config might not be pointing to the right place. Just do a google search and see what you might be able to find. But for now you have it working.